# Wordpress - Form does not filter the results of taxonomies

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, filters, taxonomy, forms

I created a plugin that uses an array, specific to which posts I want to give my taxonomy so that I can create custom categories, the name of this taxonomy is: `categoria`

We are talking about an event booking so obviously each event can be different from the other, each event can be searched by the date that is enclosed within the meta_value of the meta key:`metakey_AMC_data`

example:

form:

```
<form method="get" id="advanced-searchform" role="search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div class="md-form">

        <input type="hidden" name="search" value="advanced">
        <input
                type="text"
                name="date-picker-example"
                id="date-picker-example"
                class="text-white form-control datepicker"
        >
    <input class="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Cerca" />
</form>
```

output data:

```
<?php
// Get data from URL into variables
$_name = $_GET['date-picker-example'];

$today = date('Ymd');
// Start the Query
$v_args = array(
    'post_type'     =>  array('eventi-suite'), // your CPT
    'numberpost'    => -1,
    'meta_value'    =>  $_name, // looks into everything with the keyword from your 'name field'
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'metakey_AMC_data',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'metakey_AMC_data',
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'value'     => $today,
        ),
    ),

);
$vehicleSearchQuery = new WP_Query( $v_args );

// Open this line to Debug what's query WP has just run
//var_dump($vehicleSearchQuery->request);

// Show the results
if( $vehicleSearchQuery->have_posts() ) :
    while( $vehicleSearchQuery->have_posts() ) : $vehicleSearchQuery->the_post();
        ?><div style="padding-top: 25px;" class="col-md-6"><!-- Card -->
        <!-- Card -->
        <?php


        include('content/home_page/card.php');

        ?>
        <!-- Card -->
        <!-- Card -->
        <?php
        // Assumed your cars' names are stored as a CPT post title
        ?></div><?php
    endwhile;
else :
    ?><div style="text-align: center;padding-top: 25px;" class="col-md-12"><?php
    _e( 'Ci dispiace, non abbiamo nessun evento da proporti nella data che hai immesso. <br> Prova con un altra data.', 'textdomain' );
    ?></div><?php
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

and up here everything works perfectly.

example of url:

```
https://sitename.xxx/?search=advanced&date-picker-example=30-09-2019
```

now begin problem, because i implemented in the form the part about the taxonomy

```
<form method="get" id="advanced-searchform" role="search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div class="md-form">

        <input type="hidden" name="search" value="advanced">
        <input
                type="text"
                name="date-picker-example"
                id="date-picker-example"
                class="text-white form-control datepicker"
        >
        <label class="text-white" for="date-picker-example">Seleziona data</label>
        <?php

        /* NEW PART */

        $terms = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categoria',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ));
        ?>
        <select
                name="categoria_evento"
                id="categoria_evento"
                class="browser-default custom-select">
            <option disabled selected>Categorie Eventi</option>
            <?php
            foreach ($terms as $term)
            {
                echo "<option value='{$term->slug}'>{$term->name}</option>";
            }

            /* END NEW PART */

            ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Cerca" />
</form>
```

output date:

```
<?php
// Get data from URL into variables
$_name = $_GET['date-picker-example'];
$categoria = $_GET['categoria_evento'];
$today = date('Ymd');
// Start the Query
$v_args = array(
    'post_type'     =>  array('eventi-suite'), // your CPT
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_value'    =>  $_name, // looks into everything with the keyword from your 'name field'
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'metakey_AMC_data',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array
        (
            'key'     => 'metakey_AMC_data',
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'value'     => $today,

        ),
    ),
    'tax_query' => get_terms(array
    (
        array
        (
            'taxonomy' => 'categoria',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $categoria, /*RICHIAMO LA VARIABILE DEL FORM TASSONOMIE*/
            'hide_empty' => false,
        )
    )

));
$vehicleSearchQuery = new WP_Query( $v_args );

// Open this line to Debug what's query WP has just run
print_r($vehicleSearchQuery->request);

// Show the results
if( $vehicleSearchQuery->have_posts() ) :
    while( $vehicleSearchQuery->have_posts() ) : $vehicleSearchQuery->the_post();
        ?><div style="padding-top: 25px;" class="col-md-6"><!-- Card -->
        <!-- Card -->
        <?php


        include('content/home_page/card.php');

        ?>
        <!-- Card -->
        <!-- Card -->
        <?php
        // Assumed your cars' names are stored as a CPT post title
        ?></div><?php
    endwhile;
else :
    ?><div style="text-align: center;padding-top: 25px;" class="col-md-12"><?php
    _e( 'Ci dispiace, non abbiamo nessun evento da proporti nella data che hai immesso. <br> Prova con un altra data.', 'textdomain' );
    ?></div><?php
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

but the result I get is that it only filters me by date, but it doesn't filter me by taxonomy, so by entering for example 09/30/2019 and aperitiv taxonomy, it shows me all the events of the date I entered but of all the taxonomies, why?

example url:

```
https://namesite.xxx/categoria/aperitivi/?search=advanced&date-picker-example=30-09-2019
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code for search using date and category.

```
$_name = $_GET['date-picker-example'];
$categoria = $_GET['categoria_evento'];
$today = date('Ymd');
// Start the Query
$v_args = array(
    'post_type'     =>  array('eventi-suite'), // your CPT
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_value'    =>  $_name, // looks into everything with the keyword from your 'name field'
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'metakey_AMC_data',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array
        (
            'key'     => 'metakey_AMC_data',
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'value'     => $today,

        ),
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'categoria',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $categoria
        )
    );

));
$vehicleSearchQuery = new WP_Query( $v_args );
```